# Separating and Comparing Strings from a Text File in AHK

Tags: string, loops, user-interface, autohotkey

I'm running into a bit of a problem, but I feel so close to solving it. I have a text file with Usernames and Passwords separated with a pipe:

```
;info.txt
user1|pass1
user2|pass2
user3|pass3
user4|pass4
user5|pass5
user6|pass6
user7|pass7
user8|pass8
user9|pass9
user10|pass10
```

and here's the code:

```
Gui, -SysMenu
Gui, Add, Button, , Log in
getUsers()
Gui, Add, Button, , Exit
Gui, Show
Return


getUsers()
{
    userList := ""
    loop
    {

        FileReadLine, line, info.txt, %A_Index%
        if ErrorLevel
            Break
        getUsers := StrSplit(line, "|")
        userList .= getUsers[1] "|"

    }

    Gui, Add, ListBox, h100 vChoice, %userList%
}

ButtonLogin:
MsgBox, You chose %Choice%.
Gui, Submit, NoHide
Return

ButtonExit:
ExitApp
Return
```

I used StrSplit() to separate the User from Pass and then delimit the Users to get them into proper format for the ListBox. Everything loads just fine, but when I select one from the list and hit "Log in," the first one doesn't give me any result then the correct results are delayed by one. Example:

```
Click user1 > You chose .
Click user5 > you chose user1.
Click user3 > you chose user5.
```

Also, if anyone has a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. It was a problem with:

```
ButtonLogin:
MsgBox, You chose %Choice%.
Gui, Submit, NoHide
Return
```

The MsgBox was happening *BEFORE* Submit was going through. Fixed:

```
ButtonLogin:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
MsgBox, You chose %Choice%.
Return
```

Comment: please accept your own answer(s) if your issue was solved by it.